# Add global php file to local machine

Tags: php, function, global

I'd like to have a few functions available globally on my development machines. For instance I'd like to have a shortcut for defining xdebug's max depth when using var_dump(). I usually keep it low so even with highly complex structures it doesn't get out of hand, but I'd like to have a shortcut to be able to define it as I need it without having to look up the config value online every time.

Another use case would be ensuring that error reporting is set to E_ALL and errors are shown, so instead of writing 4/5 lines of code I could just use a function that's always available on my local machine.

Is there a way to have a file globally included, anytime/anywhere?

Comment: You can do that with several ways. For now try using .htaccess file to do so. Here are the examples and tutorial https://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in **php.ini** file via 2 configurations :

```
; Automatically add files before PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-prepend-file
auto_prepend_file =

; Automatically add files after PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-append-file
auto_append_file =
```